# Powershell - how to extract substring

Tags: powershell, path

I am new in learning powershell. Trying to extract "Testfile.txt" from the Azure Data lake Store path  `\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt` in my Powershell Script. I am using `("\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt" -split '\')[0]`.

This is showing the error

```
parsing "\" - Illegal \ at end of pattern.
At line:1 char:1
+ ("\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt" -split '\')[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: FYI: The exact reason for your error is because -split uses regex and \ is a regex character. The answer below uses the .split method which does not use regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split-path` cmdlet with the `-leaf` parameter to get the filename with extenstion :
`split-path "\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt" -leaf`

If you absolutly want to stick with your split approach you need to select the last element (`[-1]` instead of `[0]` which is the first element) : `"\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt".split('\')[-1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help. split-path "\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt" -leaf works.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 methods worked for me:

```
split-path "H:\Documents\devops\tp-mkt-SPD-38.4.10.msi" -leaf
```

tp-mkt-SPD-38.4.10.msi

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("C:\abc\xyz\test.txt")
```

test.txt

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\abc\xyz\test.txt")
```

test

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help. split-path "\data\sb\published\Juned\Testfile.txt" -leaf works.